# C# Google Docs. How to check if a user is currently editing the document?

Tags: c#, google-docs, google-docs-api

For my project i need to sync a bunch of XLS files between a SQL server and Google docs (both ways).
When a user is editing a document, this document needs to be skipped and added to a queue. This is all not a problem, but i am unable to find anything about it in the documentation.
Does anyone know something more about this?

So any help is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I couldn't attempt anything because i couldn't find anything about it. I have checked in the documentation, the properties, googled it. Nothing shows up :(

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2016, Google has not provided any "current users" API.

A work-around based on using an Add-on's `onOpen()` trigger to note users who have opened a spreadsheet is discussed in the [Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/8-GS4e_X2_4). That approach could be adopted for documents as well, with a suitable place to store information about who has opened the document. (In your case, a table on the SQL server may suffice.) You'd also need to devise a way to determine when a user is no longer editing - and there is no built-in "onClose()" trigger to help with that. (It's the cloud, so the whole idea of "open" is imprecise.)

Ultimately - I don't think it matters whether a user is currently editing a document. All their edits are being made on their own copy, which is being synchronized with a master copy. Your service would in turn be given its own copy, which you'd presumably snapshot for archival / synchronization with your SQL server.